# Customizable and synced keyboard shortcuts in Firefox

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, sync

[This mozilla support site](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly) says

> Note: Keyboard shortcuts can be customized using the [Customizable Shortcuts](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/customizable-shortcuts/) extension.

However, the keyboard shortcuts are not synced to other computers. This seems to be on the [TODO list](https://github.com/ttaubert/customizable-shortcuts) of the extension, but has not been implemented yet (see [also](https://github.com/ttaubert/customizable-shortcuts/issues/36), where I bumped the issue).

**Is there an extension which allows synced customized keyboard shortcuts?**

I'm awarding the bounty to the best effort answer, but still think this problem isn't solved yet.

Answer (score 2):

There could be a workaround with syncing it over the net until better solution is provided.

In Linux the file is stored at:

```
./jetpack/customizable-shortcuts@timtaubert.de/simple-storage/store.json
```

under your profile folder:

```
~/.mozilla/firefox/somename.default
```

You can sync it every time you run and exit from Firefox. Here is my example script which copies the file from Dropbox folder on the Firefox start and stores the file in Dropbox folder at it exits.

**It works just fine by running this script from your Desktop. Double click the script to run Firefox and your Shortcuts Add On is always synchronized**

Here is the script, but change you `profile.default` folder name:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec cp /home/ruslan/Dropbox/store.json  /home/ruslan/.mozilla/firefox/apcbgfp7.default/jetpack/customizable-shortcuts@timtaubert.de/simple-storage &

/usr/bin/firefox &

while [ `pidof firefox` ]
do
wait `pidof firefox`
done

#exec ./closing_script
exec cp /home/ruslan/.mozilla/firefox/apcbgfp7.default/jetpack/customizable-shortcuts@timtaubert.de/simple-storage/store.json /home/ruslan/Dropbox
```

*Just as a little bit extra info.* to find the difference I simply changed in `Windows & Tabs -> Select Last Tab` from <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> with <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> saved both files and it gave the next diff for both store.json.

```
1c1
< {"overlays":[]}
\ No newline at end of file
---
> {"overlays":[{"_type":"overlay","key":{"_type":"key","id":"key_selectLastTab"},"shortcut":{"_type":"shortcut","keycode":"VK_0","modifiers":{"_type":"modifiers","modifiers":["alt"]}}}]}
\ No newline at end of file
(END)
```

Comment: thanks for this contribution, +1. I didn't know the `wait` command, thanks for making me aware of it. I personally use `git` and symlinks instead of Dropbox, but this script might be useful for others. PS: can you clarify what you meant in your last paragraph?

Comment: You can modify this script to do work you need, like copying or running `git` command. In the last paragraph I just point out how changing one field (one keyboard hot keys combination) in the shortcuts, from default to user's one, affected on `store.json` file. It is just an output in `diff` format for both files `store.json`: default and modified.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of another such add-on, but
it seems to me that this add-on stores its data on Windows in the file:

`C:\Users\<user-name>\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<profile-name>\jetpack\customizable-shortcuts@timtaubert.de\simple-storage\store.json`

So you might try copying this file until the TODO list of the extension gets implemented.
Getting in touch with the developer and adding your voice to this demand might speed it up.

Comment: I'm using Linux, but the file location is similar. I could use git to sync the file. This is not very convenient, though.